# Why does my youtube data v3 exceeded quota error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api

So I'm making a get request to the youtube api and this is the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\">quota</a>.",
                "domain": "youtube.quota",
                "reason": "quotaExceeded"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that I haven't used my quota at all for at least 2 months and as shown below there is indeed 0 usage. But I still get the above response when trying to access the api.

[image]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description of the issue and the screenshot shared, most probably your project has been disabled or restricted due to inactivity. Here you can find a document with the "Youtube API Services - Developer Policies" [1].

In section D clause 4 you can find the part related to inactivity and the restriction of quota:

"**YouTube reserves the right to disable or curtail your access to, or use of, specific YouTube API Services if your API Project has been inactive for 90 consecutive days. For example, YouTube could revoke your API Credentials, or reduce (or eliminate) your API Project's quotas for specific YouTube API Services**. If your API Client's quota is reduced or eliminated, you may reapply for quota or a quota extension, and YouTube will review that application based on YouTube’s determination of your expected use of the YouTube API Services."

[1] https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#d.-accessing-youtube-api-services